# Mongodb Nodejs: return undefined after callback of an exported function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to the Node.js world. I've connected node to my MongoDB server. Now I want to write my module for MongoDB's CRUD operations but when I call `find`, it returns `undefined`.

How can I solve this problem?

**main.js**

```
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/movie";
    var result;
    var crud = require('./crud.js');

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("movie");
      var test=crud.findAll(db,dbo,"test");
      console.log(test);
      });

    var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Listening on "+host+":"+port);
    })
```

**crud.js**

```
    exports.findAll = function(db, dbo, collection){
    dbo.collection(collection).find({}).toArray(function(err,result){
    if (err) throw err;
        db.close();
        return result;
    });
    }
```

Comment: Try use `module.exports = { findAll: function (db, dbo, collection) {...} }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `findAll` is not returning a value for that reason the value of `test` is `undefined`. You have to deal with the callback result or do an implementation based on Promise.

Comment: Yes, I don an implementation based on Promise and now it work.